# saving user input after creating new textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

**When a user presses the "New Box" after entering information in previous boxes created, I don't want the old data entered by the user to be erase when the New Box button is pressed. How do I save the old user entered data when a new TextBox is created?**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var boxCount=1;
    var boxName=0;
    function newBox(){
     var boxName="Box_"+boxCount;
     document.getElementById('box').innerHTML+='<br><input type="text" name="'+boxName+'" placeholder="'+boxName+'"/><br>';
     boxCount+=1;
    }
    </script>

</head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="newBox()">New Box</button>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <span id="box"></span><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

element.innerHTML destroys all element's childs.

If you want to keep child elements, you need to use DOM functions. element.appendChild() is what you are looking for.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var boxCount=1;
        var boxName=0;

        function newBox()
        {
            var input           = document.createElement("input");
            input.type          = "text";
            input.name          = "Box_" + boxCount;
            input.placeholder   = "Box_" + boxCount;
            document.getElementById('box').appendChild(input);

            var new_line = document.createElement("br");
            document.getElementById('box').appendChild(new_line);

            boxCount++;
        }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="newBox()">New Box</button>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <span id="box"></span><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, you can get all textbox values on server side, as an array, by replacing `input.name = "Box_" + boxCount;` by `input.name = "Box[" + boxCount + "]"`. Sometimes dealing with this one is easier.

Comment: Could you please give an example appendChild() code I could use to accomplish the goal I am looking for?